# Ruby string pass by reference function parameter

Tags: ruby, pass-by-reference

Ruby noob here

I understand ruby does pass by reference for function parameters

However, I am getting the feeling this is slightly different from conventional c/c++ style pass by reference

Sample code:

```
def test1(str)
    str += ' World!'
end

def test2(str)
    str << ' World!'
end

str = 'Hello'

test1(str)
p str # Hello

test2(str)
p str # Hello World!
```

I would expect `test1` to also return `Hello World!` if I were using references in c/c++.

This is simply out of curiosity -- any explanations would be appreciated

Comment: Your understanding is wrong – Ruby is pass by value, although the concept does not really apply. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand ruby does pass by reference for function parameters

Ruby is strictly pass-by-value, always. There is no pass-by-reference in Ruby, ever.

> This is simply out of curiosity -- any explanations would be appreciated

The simple explanation for why your code snippet doesn't show the result you would expect for pass-by-reference is that Ruby isn't pass-by-reference. It is pass-by-value, and your code snippet proves that.

Here is a small snippet that demonstrates that Ruby is, in fact, pass-by-value and not pass-by-reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def is_ruby_pass_by_value?(foo)
  foo << <<~HERE
    More precisely, it is call-by-object-sharing!
    Call-by-object-sharing is a special case of pass-by-value, 
    where the value is always an immutable pointer to a (potentially mutable) value.
  HERE
  foo = 'No, Ruby is pass-by-reference.'
  return
end

bar = ['Yes, of course, Ruby *is* pass-by-value!']

is_ruby_pass_by_value?(bar)

puts bar
# Yes, of course, Ruby *is* pass-by-value!,
# More precisely, it is call-by-object-sharing!
# Call-by-object-sharing is a special case of pass-by-value, 
# where the value is always an immutable pointer to a (potentially mutable) value.
```

Ruby *does* however allow mutation of objects, it is *not* a purely functional language like Haskell or Clean.

Comment: This is the first time I see on SO highly upvoted answer, which does not answer the question at all and is not helpful. The question was: why `test2` bahaves differently to `test1`, And the correct answer really lies in the different behaviour of operators `+=` and `<<` as all other answers show. What is wrong here?

Comment: I interpret the question differently. The OP talks about pass-by-reference multiple times. He explicitly asks why `test1` fails to demonstrate pass-by-reference, even though he has been told that Ruby is pass-by-reference. And the correct answer to that is to trust the code, which clearly demonstrates that Ruby is *not* pass-by-reference (otherwise the OP's code would have worked as expected) instead of whoever told him that Ruby is pass-by-reference. [Here's a small snippet that demonstrates Ruby is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference.](http://ideone.com/yWbRGE)

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding this... So ruby (like java) is pass by value because the pointer to an object is being duplicated in the parameter. Hence the first example doesn't work because it assigns another value to the pointer. However, the second example works because it manipulates the object the pointer is pointing to. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @jrhee17: Exactly. It is pass-by-value, where the value being passed is a pointer to a potentially mutable object. In the second example, you dereference the pointer (since everything is a pointer in Ruby, there is no explicit syntax for referencing and dereferencing, it is all implicit) and mutate the object itself.

Comment: I believe, "Ruby is pass-by-value" is a... half-truth? Misleading? Incomplete? The correct statement is, "Ruby is pass-by-value, but the values it passes are references." And that second part is hidden in the comment of your snippet.

Comment: @x-yuri: I really, really, really, heavily dislike that statement, because it is terribly misleading, since the term "reference" in your statement means something significantly different than the term "reference" in "pass-by-reference", which is exactly what leads to this confusion. C# supports both pass-by-reference and pass-by-value and Ruby behaves *exactly* like C# in pass-by-value mode. C++ supports both pass-by-reference and pass-by-value and Rub behaves *exactly* like C++ in pass-by-value mode. If Ruby behaves exactly like what we call "pass-by-value" in other languages, I don't see a …

Comment: … reason to call it anything else in Ruby. People have invented terms like "call-by-object-sharing", "call-by-object", "call-by-sharing", etc. but all those are *still* special cases of pass-by-value. In this particular case, the OP had been taught that Ruby is pass-by-reference, had written code under the assumption that Ruby is pass-by-reference, and was confused why the code doesn't work when he had been taught that Ruby is pass-by-reference and the code thus should have worked.

Comment: Terribly misleading for a person coming from C*? Probably, but pass-by-value is misleading at least for me. Even though I think I know how it works in those languages. There if you pass by reference, you pass a reference to a variable (not the value that the variable holds which in its turn might be a reference), and as such the callee can change the value the variable holds (not just the value the variable refers to). "Ruby is pass-by-value" is misleading for me because the first thing that comes to mind when I hear "pass-by-value" is, "Oh, the callee can't change what I pass."...

Comment: ...So let me try it this way, "In Ruby every variable holds a reference to a value. And technically Ruby is pass-by-value. But the 'value' in 'pass-by-value' is always a reference. So the callee can change the value the argument referes to, but not the value the argument holds (which is always a reference)...

Comment: ...Javascript is pass-by-value as well, but in Javascript a variable might contain a primitive value (not a reference), and in Javascript primitive types are immutable. So a callee receives either a primitive value, or a reference. If it's a reference, see above, if a primitive value, there's no way for the callee to affect the argument."

Answer (score 1):

In the first case a new object was created when you did `str += ' World!'`

```
str = "Hello"
=> "Hello"
str.object_id
=> 69867706917360
str += " World"
=> "Hello World"
str.object_id
=> 69867706885680

str = "Hello"
=> "Hello"
str.object_id
=> 69867706856200
str << " World"
=> "Hello World"
str.object_id
=> 69867706856200

str = "Hello"
=> "Hello"
str.object_id
=> 69867706786780
str.freeze
=> "Hello"
str << " World"
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
str += " World"
=> "Hello World"
```

> "<<" is a Binary Left Shift Operator. The left operands value is moved left by the number of bits specified by the right operand.

So "<<" doesn't create a new string, `str.contact("World")` doesn't create a new string as well.
The method test1 doesn't have to do anything with the returned result , you can try this method :

```
def test1(str)
    str.concat(' World!')
end
```

Comment: ""<<" is a Binary Left Shift Operator" No, not here. It's just a method of a string which modifies it(appends another string).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following adaption of your test, by showing the object_id of your object you can easily see if it is the same or not. Test1 returns another String object because of the += concatenation but it is not used afterward.
This looks like passed by reference but in reality it is the value of the pointer to the object that is passed. The best explenation I could find for this is [here](http://robertheaton.com/2014/07/22/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/) , the author calls it pass-reference-by-value

```
def test1(str)
    p ["in test1 before", str.object_id]
  str += ' World!'
  p ["in test1 after", str.object_id]
  str
end

def test2(str)
    p ["in test2", str.object_id]
  str << ' World!'
end

str = 'Hello'
p ["in main", str.object_id]

test1(str)
p str # Hello
p ["after test1", str.object_id]

test2(str)
p str 
p ["after test2", str.object_id]
```

Gives

```
["in main", 12363600]
["in test1 before", 12363600] # the same object, so pointer to object passed by value    
["in test1 after", 12362976] # returns a new object, the old is unchanged
"Hello"
["after test1", 12363600] # idem
["in test2", 12363600]
"Hello World!"
["after test2", 12363600]
# still the same object
```

Answer (score 0):

STRING IS REFERENCED, in ruby except value like numbers, `true`, `false`, `nil`, others are referenced.

```rb
a = "hello"
b = a
a.replace("Hola")
p a # Hola
p b # Hola
```

You would wanna add the magic comment at the beginning.:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
a = "hello"
b = a
a.replace("Hola") #  can't modify frozen String: "hello" (FrozenError)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def test1(str)
    str += ' World!'
end
```

operator `+=` is a syntactic sugar in ruby. Expression `a += b` translates to `a = a + b`. Operator `+` applied on `String` instance creates new String, which is a concatenation of the two arguments. That is why str is not modified in the first case.

Also I'd like to correct your statement:

*I understand ruby does pass by reference for function parameters*

Actually ruby passes by reference every parameter except the "value types" - ie. values `nil`, `true`, `false` and instances of class `Fixnum`

Comment: You are confusing _pass by reference_ with _pass by value_. The former would allow the method to modify the passed variable, i.e. assign another value to it. But that is not possible in Ruby because you don't receive a reference to the variable. In that sense, Ruby is _pass by value_ – by assigning to `str`, you are merely changing a local variable without affecting the variable in the caller's scope.

Comment: @Stefan - not true. In Ruby, most parameters are passed by reference. In more detaile I described that in the latter part of the answer. Btw: It is also stated in the question itself - `test2` function does modify the string object, which is passed to the function, by its _reference_.

Comment: `test2` modifies the object the variable is referring to, but not the variable itself. _Pass by reference_ means that the method can modify the variable, i.e. it can change the caller's variable by assigning another value to the passed argument.

Comment: @Stefan - sorry, but you seem a little confused about the subject. _Pass by reference_ means that the method can modify the _object_ simply because it has the reference (pointer) to that object. It is exactly what `test2` function does. It modifies the string with initial value of "Hello", which is _passed by reference_ to that function.

Comment: @petrch: If Ruby were pass-by-reference, the OP's code would have worked, and this question wouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: @petrch: No, pass-by-reference means that the method can modify the *reference*. Modifying the *object* is a question of mutability. Nobody here claimed that Ruby is a purely functional language that doesn't allow modifying objects. It clearly does.

Comment: @jörg-w-mittag - Huh? _Pass by reference_ means "passing the reference". _Pass by value means_ "make a copy" of the object. Mutability of the object is another topic.